# Keep data on the database even deleted on the site

Tags: mysql

on my mysql server (phpmyadmin) i have a database with important info, i can't lose this data but because of the php and site's objective the data disappear from the database.
There is anyway to keep the data forever on the database till the admin remove it?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not admin questions. Post a sample of code that you have tried and are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 2):

Add a column on the table called is_deleted and set it to true when you delete that row. Then exclude theese rows on all gets.

Alot of ORMs  make this super simple to implment on the application side.

This approach is known as a 'soft delete' and can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @rahicks posted, I highly recommend that you also look into doing database backups. [Database Backup Methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html) from the official MySQL documentation is a good starting point.

That way, even if by accidental programming logic etc. you lose data, you have a backup.

You can automate the backup process by setting up CRON jobs; this article gives a good run down on how to do that: [How to back up MySQL databases using cron jobs](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/mysql-database-backups-using-cron-jobs)

(having backups is always, in general and most cases, a good thing!)

Answer (score 0):

Add a column called status.

All the query on website, you could do it when status  is 1.

Usually you should never delete data from database. Always keep a column called STATUS with smallint of 1.

Status = 0 -> not active mean deleted 
Status = 1 -> active

And on your website when you select a query to show some data at the end you put that WHERE status = 1 ;

This is how I do it.

On your form if a registration or anything

Put a hidden input called status and put value you want .....